# Not Reading Nfc 4K Card details in Android

Tags: android, nfc, card

I want to read NFC 4K card details, Its not reading the data, Here is the Code I use,

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature  android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

**nfc_tech_filter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {
public static final String TAG = " --NFC-- " + MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (nfcAdapter == null) {
        showToast("No NFC found...");
    } else {
        showToast("NFC Enables Device...");
        enableReaderMode();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showToast("On Resume...");
    enableReaderMode();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    showToast("On Pause...");
    disableReaderMode();
}


private void showToast(String message) {
    Log.d(TAG, message);
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Show Toast Exception : " + message);
    }
}


private void enableReaderMode() {
    showToast("Enabling reader mode...");
    Activity activity = MainActivity.this;
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity);
    if (nfcAdapter != null) {
        nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(activity, this,  Integer.MAX_VALUE, null);
    }
}

private void disableReaderMode() {
    showToast("Disabling reader mode...");
    Activity activity = MainActivity.this;
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity);
    if (nfcAdapter != null) 
        nfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(activity);
}


@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
    Log.d(TAG, "New tag discovered...");
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "New Intent...");
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your are not handling your intent data in onNewIntent(). onNewIntent() will be call whenever you scan your NFC card.
Like below example :

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
super.onNewIntent(intent);
Log.d(TAG, "New Intent...");
handleIntent(intent);
}


private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
val bundle = intent.extras
    if (bundle != null) {
        
Log.e(TAG,intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG))
    }
}
```

**Edited**

You need to call this method from onResume() after adding adapter.

```
private fun setupForegroundDispatch(activity : Activity, adapter 
    : NfcAdapter) {
    val intent = Intent(activity.applicationContext, 
    activity.javaClass)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    val pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.applicationContext, 0, 
    intent, 0)
    //        val filters = arrayOfNulls<IntentFilter>(1)
    //        val techList = arrayOf<Array<String>>()
    val ndef = IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)
    val filters = arrayOf(ndef)
    //        val techList = arrayOf<Array<String>>()
    val techList = arrayOf(arrayOf(NfcV::class.java.name))

    // Notice that this is the same filter as in our manifest.
    filters[0] = IntentFilter()
    filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)
    filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
    try {
        filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN)
    }
    catch (e : IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Check your mime type.")
    }
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, 
   filters, techList)
}
```

Like below :

```
private void enableReaderMode() {
showToast("Enabling reader mode...");
Activity activity = MainActivity.this;
nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity);
if (nfcAdapter != null) {
    nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(activity, this,  
 Integer.MAX_VALUE, null);
 setupForegroundDispatch(this,nfcAdapter);
}
}
```

[Follow this tutorial for more info](https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-nfc-read-and-write-example/)

Comment: I added a Log there, It also not showing on Logcat..

Comment: are you getting log of New Intent?

Comment: Its not invoking onNewIntent() method

Comment: As SHIDHIN.T.S is using `enableReaderMode` not using `enableForegroundDispatch` then `onNewIntent` will never be called as this is the wrong method `onTagDiscovered` is where the NFC detection is handled.

Comment: I have added my method.Please check the answer

Comment: Can i know your device name?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `enableReaderMode` you don't need the `onNewIntent` method.

Also the `intent-filter` in the manifest and nfc_tech_filter.xml might not be required (They are not need if you don't want your app to be started by an NFC Tag if not running, then you would handle the NFC Intent in `onCreate`)

What you have not done is setup `enableReaderMode` correctly.

```java
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(nfcAdapter!= null && nfcAdapter.isEnabled) {
            Bundle options = new Bundle();
            options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);

            nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this,
                    this,
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
                    options);
        }

    }
```

Turning off `NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS` is optional if you want to generate your own notification of reading instead of the OS doing it.

Note that the newer NFC API of `enableReaderMode` gives you more control that the older `enableForegroundDispatch` and is much more reliable than `enableForegroundDispatch` when writing to NFC Tags and it does not have some of the Negative side effects of `enableForegroundDispatch`, so I would recommend to always use `enableReaderMode` unless you want to support really old API's

Also note that using Mifare 4K cards is not recommended as well as they are a proprietary format and not supported by all Android Hardware (not matter which API you use)

Comment: if he does not use onNewIntent() then where he will receive data while tapping NFC?

Comment: @Nadim Ansari the data is delivered to the `onTagDiscovered` method in a separate thread with the newer and better API.

Comment: This also not working, I am trying to read data from 4K card and ATM cards

Comment: its not invoking   onTagDiscovered(Tag tag)  method

Comment: It is possible that your hardware does not support reading of the 4k mifare cards because they are a non standard format, but the contactless bank card is a standard format so should be detected but they are not easy to read any data from them and definitely won't have any ndef data on them.

Comment: Also updated answer as you really should check that the `nfcAdaptor.isEnabled` is true (Nfc Hardware is present and is turned on in the Android settings)